# How can I run Carla simulator on windows VM?

Tags: carla

I am using MacBook M2 pro chip and trying to run Carla simulator on parallels VM but it doesn't work and give me this error The application was unable to start correctly (Oxc0000142). Click OK to close the application. how can I fix that error ?.

I tried to install different VMs and it is the same problem and tried Ubuntu, it gives me the same massage . Is it because Apple silicon ship and GPU or there is a method to fix it

Comment: It might be missing DLLs, or some change they did after version 09.12+, but this (old!, Sep 2021) problem was not answered: https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/4609